# Artifacts and problems with shadows of directional light & point light

Tags: reactjs, react-three-fiber

So I'm using React, Three Fiber as well as the drei library and cannon for physics.

I am making an apartment viewer as a personal project in which you can walk around in - so far everything works fine. To make it later on possible to load in the apartment model from a database (and make the creation process easier for multiple models), the transformations for the light switches, aktivatable point lights and the apartments collision boxes are copied from objects within the gltf file.

To prevent the collision boxes from rendering or otherwise effecting the rendering process, they are made invisible. (I also tried to set child.castShadow = false with no effect).
For some reason the shadows are corrupted: [unwanted point light shadows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ArSyR.jpg).

I also tried to change some properties of the original child: Object3D properties in the Apartment component (the only place where the boxes could affect the shadows), without changing results.

Another thing is that there doesn't seem to be any options to adjust shadows anymore. Properties like shadowBias, shadowMapWidth etc. are [deprecated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxtmN.png). By hovering over it I get something like `@deprecated — Use shadow.mapSize.width instead`. At least I couldn't find a solution to that, also because the Three Fiber documentation isn't that extensive. Just using them doesn't work either.

Comment: After some more testing i found out, that this error occurs everytime i assign a material to the mesh in Blender. Exported .gltf files without materials cast perfect shadows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so for some reason an object with imported materials has problems receiving shadows. By setting `shadow-bias={-0.0003}` on the pointLight [(in kebab case like for every other Three property as well)](https://docs.pmnd.rs/react-three-fiber/api/objects#piercing-into-nested-properties) the shadows now obviously have a slight offset to them, but all the stripes are gone. Thanks also to the redditors that guided me to the fix for this issue!